# Missing particles while creating slices from STL

Tags: python, mesh, camera, image

I am a PhD student using Blender to extract cross sections from STL grannular assemblies with python.

I found some cross sections may lose several particles. However, when I move the cross section a little bit, it appaears again.

Please have a check of my code.
With thanks,
Jie

[image]

```
import bpy
import os

# Step 1: Import the STL file
path_in = r"C:\Users\STL"


filename_in = "G1_shrink1.0001.stl"
path_out = r"C:\Users\G1_dp0.08"
filename_out = "G1_shrink1.00_{}.tif"

filepath = os.path.join(path_in, filename_in)

bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=filepath)

obj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]


#obj.location = (-45, -15, 0)

#################
obj.rotation_euler = (0, 0, 0)
obj.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
obj.data.transform(obj.matrix_world)

# Set the pivot point to the specified location
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point = 'CURSOR'
bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = (0, 0, 0)  # set the pivot point here

# Rotate the object around the Z-axis by 90 degrees
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1.5708, orient_axis='Y', orient_type='LOCAL')

# Reset the pivot point to its default location
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point = 'MEDIAN_POINT'
##############
obj.location = (15, -15, 0)


bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# Step 2: Create a plane and position it to intersect the STL object
if bpy.context.space_data.type == 'VIEW_3D':
    bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_center()

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add()
plane = bpy.context.object
plane.scale = (30,30, 0.06)

# Step 3: Create a boolean modifier for the plane object and apply it
stl_object = bpy.data.objects[0]
mod = plane.modifiers.new(type='BOOLEAN', name='Boolean')
mod.object = stl_object
mod.operation = 'INTERSECT'

# Step 4:set the material color and background
cross_section = plane
cross_section_material = bpy.data.materials.new(name="CrossSectionMaterial")
cross_section.data.materials.append(cross_section_material)
cross_section_material.diffuse_color = (0.01, 0.01, 0.01,1)

bpy.context.scene.world.use_nodes = True
bg_node = bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeBackground")
bg_node.inputs[0].default_value = (0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1)

world_output = bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes.get("World Output")
bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.links.new(bg_node.outputs[0], world_output.inputs[0])


# Step 5: Add a camera to the scene
bpy.ops.object.camera_add(location=(0,0,60))
bpy.data.cameras['Camera'].type = 'ORTHO'
bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.context.object
stl_object.hide_render = True

# Step 6: Set the image resolution and render settings
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 350
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 350

# Step 7: Iterate through the range of Z values for the cross sections

for i in range(350):
    # Position the plane along the Z axis
    slice_L = 30
    slice_n =350
    slice_dx = slice_L/(slice_n-1)
    plane.location.z = i*slice_dx
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='Boolean')
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')
    cross_section = bpy.context.object
    # Set the ortho_scale property for the camera
    bpy.data.objects["Camera"].location = (0,0, 50+plane.location.z)
    bpy.data.cameras['Camera'].ortho_scale = 2
    # Render the current view as an image
    
    file_path = os.path.join(path_out, filename_out.format(i))
    bpy.ops.render.render()
    # Save the rendered image to disk
    
    bpy.data.images['Render Result'].save_render(file_path)
```